# Overlapping divs in HTML/CSS

Tags: css, html, overlap

I need some help with my website html/css code. The site looks nice(to me), but if someone has a small 17" monitor, or if you zoom in the website, the divs in my info bar overlap each other and it looks awful. It's messy,sorry, but I have been trying out all sorts of things I found on the net... What can I do to change that overlap?

This is my middle div:

```
<div id="mac">
<div id="mapa"><script id="_waux4i">var _wau = _wau || [];
_wau.push(["map", "sdfsdfsdv", "d3d", "420", "210", "night", "default-red"]);
(function() {var s=document.createElement("script"); s.async=true;
s.src="http://widgets.amung.us/map.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
})();</script>
</div>
<div id="qrcode"><img src="gallery/images/qrcode.png" width="600" height="86" /> </div>
</div>
```

This is the left div:

```
<div id="instagram"> some instagram iframe code</div>
```

Right div:

```
<div id="social">
<div id="social_buttons">Some rollover buttons</div> 
</div>
```

The CSS code, for them is:

```
#social_buttons{
float:right;
padding-right:20px;
padding-top:320px;
}

#social {
float:right;
width:370px;
height:350px;
background:url(gallery/images/pic.png) no-repeat;
margin-top:70px;
position:relative;
right:10px;
display: block;
}

#instagram {
float:left;
height:350px;
width:437px;
margin-left:35px;
margin-top:30px;
display: block;
}

#mapa {
height:220px;
padding-left:100px;
padding-top:100px;
background:url(gallery/images/mac.png) no-repeat;
 }

 #qrcode{
margin-top:100px;
position:absolute;
width:619px;
 }

 #mac {
margin:0 auto;
height:500px;
background:url(gallery/images/mac.png) no-repeat;
min-width:619px;
    width:619px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Could you post a link to the site, or a jfiddle illustrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use Media Queries..
for more help..read and then apply so it will b responsive so it wont overlap

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score 0):

For a start I would recommend changing your div sizes from px to %. That way it should scale when the screen size varies. This isn't the greatest choice, since it will change the scaling of your divs and may distort your content. See this answer for more options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19385846/2990189

Answer (score 0):

This is tragedy with Using "px" in your css, so to make your code work good in smaller viewport use % to assign Value to Attributes

lets Go to different Units used in css
a)Em:-Increasingly popular in web documents due to scalability and their mobile-device-friendly nature.

b)Pixels: Many web designers use pixel units in web documents in order to produce a pixel-perfect representation of their site as it is rendered in the browser. One problem with the pixel unit is that it does not scale upward for visually-impaired readers or downward to fit mobile devices.

c)Points:Points are much like pixels, in that they are fixed-size units and cannot scale in size.

d)While using the percent unit, your text remains fully scalable for mobile devices and for accessibility.

So whats The Difference is

with going to Portablity within Devices px always Sucks ..so its Time to Move toward % at your css

Comment: But how can I display something that is 350px wide with percent?

Comment: the best practise to design a page is using grid ... Draw a grid with rows and column(equal sized) on paper , and start Putting your content on the Grid ...Doing so you will get Percentage of row required and that %age will be used in Css ..simple Right?

Comment: I will try to update my CSS when I get some free time, but before that, is there any way I can make it work now? To not overlap I mean...

Comment: position:relative;
right:10px;
change it to static and see wether it works or not.... and please provide one dummy jsfiddle for same codes

Answer (score 0):

Change the display to inline-block on #mac #instagram and #social

```
display:inline-block;
```