# How can I prevent images from overlapping when the window is scaled up?

Tags: html, css

When I make the window larger, the images scale with it and eventually overlap each other.

What I want it to be:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUIhH.png

What happens when I scale window:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1aCn.png

Html:

```
<html>

<head>

</head>
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleE.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JQueryAnimation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="draw.js"></script>
    <img src="Sprites/Button.png" width="25%" id="triggerButton" style="top:50px;">
    <img src="Sprites/Primary.png" width="17%" id="primaryButton" style="top:150px;">


    </br>
        <img src="Sprites/1.png" width="15%" id="wedge1" style="top:600px;" class="spinner">
        <img src="Sprites/2.png" width="15%" id="wedge2" style="top:600px;" class="spinner">
        <img src="Sprites/3.png" width="15%" id="wedge3" style="top:600px;" class="spinner">
        <img src="Sprites/4.png" width="15%" id="wedge4" style="top:600px;" class="spinner">
        <img src="Sprites/5.png" width="15%" id="wedge5" style="top:600px;" class="spinner">
        <img src="Sprites/6.png" width="15%" id="wedge6" style="top:600px;" class="spinner">
        <img src="Sprites/7.png" width="15%" id="wedge7" style="top:600px;" class="spinner">
        <img src="Sprites/8.png" width="15%" id="wedge8" style="top:600px;" class="spinner">
        <img src="Sprites/9.png" width="15%" id="wedge9" style="top:600px;" class="spinner">
        <img src="Sprites/10.png" width="15%" id="wedge10" style="top:600px;" class="spinner">
        <img src="Sprites/11.png" width="15%" id="wedge11" style="top:600px;" class="spinner">
        <img src="Sprites/12.png" width="15%" id="wedge12" style="top:600px;" class="spinner">
</body>
```

Css:

```
#triggerButton {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;

}

#primaryButton {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;

}

.spinner{

    transform-origin:top left;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 12%;
    width: auto;
    max-width:11%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you create the jsfiddle or provide the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position: absolute pulls the elements out of the DOM rendering rules. The CSS as written tells the browser to always place these elements at X position no matter what size of the element or screen. A List Apart has an excellent article for getting a good grounding in how positining works: http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

Remove the positioning and instead use either the "display:" or "float:" properties. Things will begin to flow according to the DOM rendering rules.

In addition, make sure applied CSS classes have functional or semantic naming. Avoid using classes that make reference to design treatment since things like colors/big/small can and do change over time., ie, "whitebackground". The code is much better served using something like the "client-name" or .theme and then declaring the background color for that class or on the BODY tag.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19385846/4064180

Comment: Thanks, you helped a ton! Changing the "position:absolute;" to "display:block;" solved the scaling problem but it created another. I was using the "position:absolute" on the ".spinner" class to stack images on top of each other. If I lose the "position:absolute" the image stops scaling like I wanted it to but they stop stacking. Thanks again!

Comment: @AnthoneyKalasho wrap the spinner in a `div`, give the `div` `display:block` and then the elements inside the spinner `position:absolute`

Comment: @starvator I did that but it didn't change anything

Comment: @AnthoneyKalasho give the `div` a `height`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using percentages for the width of your buttons and spinner, give it a fixed width such as 300px.

Also, you should consider removing the position: absolute as it serves you no purpose. Instead, remove it completely and add display: block;